# The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1 in Travis for ruby cucumber automation script

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, rake, travis-ci

I am trying to run my sample work in Travis but getting below error.[Git hub project](https://github.com/Apzal/RubyCucumberWatir.git):

```
$ bundle exec rake
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby -I "lib" "/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber" --profile default
The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1.
```

Rake file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
  t.profile = 'default'
end

task :default => :features
```

.travis.yml file

```
language: ruby
rvm :
    - 2.3.3
before_install:
  - gem update --system
  - gem install bundler
gemfile: gemfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
before_install:
  - gem install rake
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer in details, with some context and explanation, so it would be more understandable?